# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar / cannot resolve "R"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I haven't found the right answer yet. This is my first Project with Android Studio and I'm almost losing my patience :). Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar is marked in red.

This is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "helloworld.spsa3.helloworldproject"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And finally this is my second Problem and i'm sure they are related. "R" cannot be resolved aswell. "R" is also marked in red.

So here's my MainActivityFragment() Class:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment{

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

}
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: This means there is some compilation issue in your Layout files or drawables. Basically anything in res folder can cause R not to be compiled

Comment: Try Build -> Clean Project

Comment: @kapsym so do you have an idea how to fix this.. have you ever had the same problem then?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat this didn't work

Comment: Check your resource file names for *invalid characters*. If **any** of them has a **single** invalid character, you won't be able to compile R.java.

Comment: @ModularSynth which ones do you mean exactly?

Comment: You can only use `a-z0-9._` and the file names can't begin with a number.

Comment: have you try to invalidate and restart the project ?

Comment: @ModularSynth so i've just checked this... nothing seems to be wrong in the resource files (no ivalid charachter, no file starting with a number)and it's still not working

Comment: @Tanamo i did..still not working

Comment: Invalid characters include spaces and upper case ones.

Comment: @ModularSynth I did not use any spaces or upper case letters for filenames

Comment: change the buildtoolversion to 25 .0.2 and the support dependency to 25.2.0 and rebuild project

Comment: @Tanamo by support dependency you mean this: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
right?

Comment: yes @ Sarina.
if it doesn't work
change the parent to "Theme.AppCompat.Light". and customize your theme.

Answer (score 0):

`R.java` is a generated file. If you're getting errors like this

[image]

it's because `R.java` failed to generate. This can be caused by bad filenames or by bad contents inside a resource file.

Look for the "Messages" view in Android Studio (or open via the menu `View -> Tool Windows -> Messages`). When you do a clean rebuild of your project, you should see an error related to why `R.java` couldn't be generated. For my example above, the error message is:

> /StackOverflow/app/src/main/res/drawable/illegal-name.xml
>
> Error: '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore

So you can see that my `illegal-name.xml` resource can't have the hyphen, and should probably be changed to `legal_name.xml`.

Or perhaps I screwed up my XML tags somewhere. Maybe in one of my string resources I didn't properly close the tag:

```
<string name="label_register">REGISTER<string>
```

Now the "Messages" view shows me this error:

> /StackOverflow/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
>
> Error: The element type "string" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "`</string>`".

Follow the errors in your "Messages" view to find the problem.

Comment: Hey Ben thanks. So i did the gradle sync and after this was done a few Errors where shown in the Messages like: "Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1". There Errors are all for the file "build.gradle". So do you know any other ideas or solutions for my problem?

Comment: This is also showing in the Message-View."Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugUnitTestApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443

Comment: And this is the last line, that didn't fit in the other comment: >Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443[jcenter.bintray.com/5.153.35.248] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: This may be also important: In my AndroidManifest.XML in the activity theres my Name which ist marked with a red line. And it Looks like this: android:name="MainActivity"

Comment: The first sounds like you have `compile javax.inject:javax.inject:1` somewhere in your `build.gradle` file, and the gradle build process is unable to download that library from any of the repositories you have set up. The second can be fixed by changing `name="MainActivity"` to `name=".MainActivity"` (add a dot before the class name).

Answer (score 0):

If rebuild or clean didn't help, try to do: File - Invalidate Caches / Restart